# После установки docker на виртуалку пропадает доступ к локальным ресурсам vpn

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vmware

Win 10 подключен к рабочей сети vpn через openVPN, в системе через VMware workstation установлена ubuntu 20.04, как только устанавливают docker в ubuntu, сразу же пропадает доступ к локальным ресурсам vpn. В настройках все облазил, но не понимаю в чем может быть дело. В linux я новичек.
Схему -> ubuntu из win 10 менять не хотелось бы т.к. это домашний ноут временно используемый для работы. Спасибо.

Comment: Ты точно установил факт что после установки docker летить vpn а не каких то манипуляций с VMware workstation ? или вообще иных манипуляций?

Comment: 100%, пробовал уже не раз, в момент окончания установки докера сразу перестают загружаться нужные ссылки, после полного удаления докера опять начинают грузиться. Нашел, что это связано с использованием hyper-v для виртуализации когда хостом является windows, но никаких решений не нашел.

Comment: Но ты ж говоришь что у тебя VMware workstation ?,hyper-v это майкрсовтовская виртуализация.И если ты ее на машину не ставил то ее как бы и нет. Так что hyper-v помоему тут точно не причем. Это так происходит когда чисты docer развернул? без всяких образов подготовленных для docer?

Comment: hyper-v в винде есть по умолчанию и используется докером, а вот то, что я его отключил чтобы зайти в vmware (этот способ представлен как самый просто для решения проблемы совместного использования докера и vmware) только сейчас вспомнил, надо в этом направлении покопать.

Так происходит сразу после инсталляции докере - sudo apt install docker-ce

Comment: Подожди есть win10-ok. hyper-v и VMware это разные продукты для виртуализации .hyper-v  это майкрасовт VMware- иная компания. На чем ты разварачивал ubuntu.? Ты чего то кашу у себя намешал в голове. hyper-v  не имеет ни каких отношений к  VMware, это программные продукты, если процессор подерживает Hyper-threading то любая из этих вертуалок будет работать.но судя что ты запустил ubuntu  с эти у тебя все ок,Только в чом ты его его запустил я так и не понял.Используя hyper-v или VMware?

Comment: Ну вот, кто-то не внимательно читает и видимо не знает как работает докер, а "каша в голове" у меня. hyper-v (докер на win10) к vmware(воркстейшн) имеет отношение, выраженное в конфликтном одновременном сосуществовании, которое в моем случае необходимо.

Comment: у меня работает win7. в ней вертуалка поднятая в VMware Workstation. На вертуалке развернут образ Ubuntu. В Ubuntu развернут docer в котором запущены образы php. nginx. mysql.memcached. На работе  запущены около 8 вертуальных серверов на hyper-v на базе winserver2008.И поверь я знаю разницу между hyper-v  и  VMware. Просто для того чтоб понять твою проблему ,Нужно понять че ты по запускал и где. Но увы чет я так и не понял.))

Comment: Обратись к любому сисадину, практику, и поверь он поймет все то что я у тебя спрашивал.Надеюсь ты найдешь решение своей проблемы, просто самому было интересно, в той связки как понимал я ,как такое может быть.

Comment: Как будто я что-то не понял из того, что ты спрашивал. Если хочешь понять, напишу еще раз по порядку - на win10 стоит VMware Workstation, через нее установлена ubuntu, в ubuntu установил docker для дампа индексов elasticsearch. В ходе выявления причины пропадания доступа к локальным ресурсам сети vpn было установлено, что доступ пропадает сразу же после инсталляции докера в ubuntu (проверено в чистой ubuntu без других действий).

Comment: Теперь объясняю причем тут hyper-v, в win10 у меня тоже стоит docker, в win10 docker устанавливается службой hyper-v, но это "под капотом", hyper-v в win10 есть из коробки т.е. пользователи не интересующиеся внутренним устройством работы докера вообще  не в курсе, что его поднимает hyper-v. В убунте же для установки докера гипервизор не нужен, эта проблема характера только при совместном использовании докера и vmware в windows.Поэтому для запуска vmware при установленном в этой же системе docker нужно останавливать службу hyper-v (есть и другие способы, не суть).

Comment: в самом первом вопросе твоем написано " в системе через VMware workstation установлена ubuntu 20.04," далее "как только устанавливают docker в ubuntu,."----------------Это был первый комент.. Теперь последний "у меня тоже стоит docker, в win10 docker устанавливается службой hyper-v," .Как бы твои же слова в которых совсем разные истории.в первой "docker в ubunt" в последнем комите уже "в win10 docker устанавливается службой hyper-v,".вот и пойми вас задающих вопросы, о чом вы вообще хотели рассказать)))